# Multidimensional arrays in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a empty 3D array in PowerShell. I saw some examples online and I have used this line to create it.

```
 $mulArr = @(@(),@(),@())
```

And I have added some values to this using the line below

```
 $mulArr+= ('a',@('b','c'),'v')
```

When I checked the length of the array above using $mulArray.Length, it is showing as desired. But I am unable to access the array elements explicitly like below.

```
$mulArr[0,0,1]
```

This is not returning any value. Please help me understand where I am going wrong with this.

Comment: what return value do you expect?

Comment: You have jagged array not multidimensional array.

Comment: Note that the relevant answer in the linked duplicate is not the accepted answer for the question (it applies better here than it did there).

Comment: @briantist I've seen that question before posting this one. But there he is explicitly mentioning the size of the multidimensional array. I don't want to do that here. I just want to see a matrix kind of output with the values I provide.

Comment: @karun10 if you want a dynamically sized array, the jagged array is the way to go. Also, what would a 3D matrix look like on a 2D screen? :-)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  I meant 3x3 kind of thing. I see what I did there.. My bad :) 
So for a dynamically sized multidimensional array, jagged array is the only way to go ?